# php dropdown - show current year starting from 2017

Tags: php, dropdown

```
<?php

echo '<select name="fromYear"';
 $starting_year  =date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'));
$current_year = date('Y');
 $ending_year = date('Y', strtotime('+10 year'));

 for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
     echo '<option value="'.$starting_year.'"';
     if( $starting_year ==  $current_year ) {
            echo ' selected="selected"';
     }
     echo ' >'.$starting_year.'</option>';
 }               
 echo '<select>';
?>
```

Hi i have this code how to modify this..to show current year and previous year starting from 2017

starting year : 2017

when in 2017 : i will only see 2017 in drop down

2018 : 2017, 2018

2019 : 2017, 2018, 2019

2020 : 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020

and so on...

Comment: Do you always want to start the list in the drop downs from 2017? If so, why not initialize $starting_year to 2017?

Comment: Yes ..i forgot to modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`do while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) to start for the current year as follows:

```
<?php
    $starting_year = 2017;
    $current_year = date('Y')*1;
    echo '<select name="years">';
    echo '<option>Select</option>';
    do {
        echo '<option value="'.$starting_year.'">'.$starting_year.'</option>';
        $starting_year++;
    }
    while ($current_year >= $starting_year);
    echo '</select>';

    ?>
```

Online [Demo](http://ideone.com/fork/nrhvUZ)

From PHP official documentation:

> do-while loops are very similar to while loops, except the truth
>   expression is checked at the end of each iteration instead of in the
>   beginning. The main difference from regular while loops is that the
>   first iteration of a do-while loop is **guaranteed to run** (the truth
>   expression is only checked at the end of the iteration), whereas it
>   may not necessarily run with a regular while loop...